# Whether to say "dans des contextes/cadres non commerciaux"

Tags: choix-de-mot

So I'm in the middle of whipping up a business-related email, and there is a need to point out the idea "*for non-commercial purposes only*", since the photos to be attached to the email are of part of the premises of our hospital and are not allowed to be posted on any website for commercial purposes.

> L'utilisation de ces photographies est autorisée exclusivement dans des **contextes** non commerciaux.
>
> {or}: L'utilisation de ces photographies est autorisée exclusivement dans des **cadres** non commerciaux.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the inconsistency between the goal expressed *not allowed to be posted on any website except our own* (very clear, very restrictive and very easy to translate) and the French translation attempts which are less restrictive (are allowed to be published or used on any website provided they are not for profit).

Comment: @jlliagre Edited. Here, I'm going for the "less restrictive" one.

Comment: Okay, then I would suggest to write both a summary sentence (*pas d'usage commercial*) **and** a reference to a licence like the one suggested by aCOSwt (upvoted). Without a legalese backing, simple sentences might be overturn by astute lawyers.

Comment: I would have said "an email concerning business".

Comment: @17522 It seems that you should say "How to write these things is tricky.", but never mind! I guess that  my having been granted the privilege to make improvements to the text of both **questions** and **answers** is a mere formality.

Comment: @17522 I think you should say "How to write these things is tricky.", but never mind; on the contrary, I am sure that both "an email that concerns business" and "an email concerning business" are both correct. I guess that the privilege that has been granted me to correct all answers and questions means nothing to you, that you see it as a  mere formality!

Comment: @17522 I have no interest in making a fuss; however as you seem so well aware of my proficiency in the English language and of my use of it on this site, you should know that I have corrected the writing of a good number of people in the membership, natives and others, and that those corrections are always accepted whithout the least discussion. We are all the better for those improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question, why don't you simply put a CC BY-NC-ND license ? https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/ . It says all to everybody... for who cares... ;)

BTW, in the french version of that web page, you'll find the appropriate translation :

*Pas d'usage commercial*

De fait et légalement c'est l' **usage** que l'on restreint. Ni le *cadre* ni le *contexte*.
Et comme par ailleurs dans ces histoires légales, si on veut faire court, il est plus facile d'être explicite sur ce qui est interdit, je te suggèrerais, si tu tiens à faire un texte :

*La reproduction à usage commercial de ces photographies est interdit.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens : That is precisely what the CC BY-NC-ND is for. Use / non commercial / no modification. Anyway, you can find other (and less restrictive) types of license on the CC home page.

Comment: Hi. Actually, their use itself is not a problem – like forwarding them to others or posting them on a private Instagram account and whatnot. And since this is not something to be written on a website, I need a complete sentence rather than something concise such as "CC BY-NC-ND" or "Pas d'usage commercial" which may well come across as too *distant*. :)